# MassTransit first run

Tags: msmq, masstransit

I'm trying out MassTransit. I wrote a small console application as showed in documentation (http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html).

What I first ran the app, it opened another console windows, and did something that looked like an installation proccess, or some kind of file copy. I remember seeing something done in the windows directory, but it was too fast to read and understand what exactly it did.

I couldn't find any information about it. I tried starting a new .NET project and running the same code - it did not repeat.

Does MassTransit install something on the system at first run? does someone knows what exactly happens on first tun?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you included the call to the method `VerifyMsmqConfiguration()` as in the quick start, then MassTransit initates any required MSMQ component installation.

The [required MSMQ components](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/ee1eab9b1964b79c99deb5dd445c6075f47157df/src/Transports/MassTransit.Transports.Msmq/Management/MsmqManagement.cs) are Core, LocalStorage, and Multicast.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I did call it.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a post explaining how to get a quick hello world Mass Transit application up and running. 
It uses RabbitMQ, but the same principles apply to MSMQ.

http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2015/04/mass-transit-with-rabbitmq-hello-world/